# jQuery split() not.... splitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bug in my code somewhere but can't see what I have done wrong.

What I have is a hidden input of facebook user id's which is populated via a jQuery UI autocomplete:

```
<input id="fbid" type="hidden" value="12345, 567890, ">
```

I then have a jQuery function which runs when the link is clicked to post to the walls of the friends.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '12345678', // App ID
        channelUrl : '/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here

    FB.login(function(response)
    {
        if (response.authResponse)
        {                                               
            $("#send-voucher").click(function() {

                // Post message to friend's wall

                var opts = {
                    message : 'This is the message',
                    name : 'This is the name',
                    link : 'http://www.opticalexpress.co.uk',
                    description : 'This is the description',
                    picture : '/voucher_valid.png'
                };

                var referees = $("#fbid").val();

                // remove last comma and space from the end of the string
                referees = $.trim(referees);
                referees = referees.substring(0, referees.length - 1);

                var referee = referees.split(',');
                referee.each(function() {

                    FB.api('/'+ referee +'/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
                    {
                        if (!response || response.error)
                        {
                            alert('Posting error occured');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('Success - Post ID: ' + response.id);
                            $("#send-voucher").hide();
                            $("#voucher-sent").fadeIn('slow');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Not logged in');
        }
    }, { scope : 'publish_stream' });
};
```

When I click to send the vouchers, the error is from the alert dialogue in my `else` statement above:

`Posting error occured`

I added in another alert to see why this was happening after the opening of the loop:

```
$.each(referee, function() {
    referee = $.trim(referee);
    alert(referee); // new alert for debugging
    ....
```

What this alert outputs surprised me as the value of `referee` is `12345, 567890` (same as the hidden input but with trailing space and last comma removed).

Therefore, jQuery doesn't seem to be splitting it correctly but it runs the loop the correct number of times as the alert box pops up twice telling me the referee and then the error. (both alert boxes show twice just to clarify). Incase this was a coincidence I tried adding more id's to the hidden input and can confirm that the alert boxes are showing the same amount of times as the number of id's.

So I was wondering what I had done wrong since the loop runs the correct amount of times but the comma separated id's don't seem to be split at all.

Comment: `split` has nothing to do with jQuery. It's part of **JavaScript**'s `String.prototype`.

Comment: Your quoted code will fail on `referee.each`. `each` isn't a function of arrays, not unless you've added it. In your smaller following code block, you show `$.each(refereee, function() ...)` which is fine, but the main code block will fail with a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: probably remove last comma from input and try <input id="fbid" type="hidden" value="12345, 567890 ">, the comma at the end will look for additional input wich is not their..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, yes I actually read that before asking my question and realised what I'd done after posting it.

Comment: Is it possible that the comma in `12345, 567890` isn't actually a comma?

Comment: @Blazemonger yeah it's definitely a comma. I'm a step closer now that I'm alerting using `$(this)` but it is an object but I can see the value if I do `alert($(this).toSource());` so trying to figure out how to get the id from the object now.

Comment: Keep debugging -- I'm not sure there's much more we can do without your original source code, which would require you sharing your FB appId with the entire world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. As mentioned by others, you are looping an array using a non-existing `.each()` method. You can use a standard `for()` loop instead. Also it's much more efficient stripping white space and excess commas using regular expressions.

Here's a simplified example, also available at http://jsfiddle.net/hJQ6W/

```
<input id="fbid" type="hidden" value="12345, 567890, ">
<script>
  var referees = $("#fbid").val();
  // trim string and remove all commas from the end of it
  referees = referees.replace(/\s/g,'').replace(/,*$/,'');
  var referee = referees.split(',');
  for(i=0; i<referee.length; i++) {
    alert('"'+referee[i]+'"');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: was actually in the middle of switching to a `for` loop when I refreshed and seen this, it solved all the problems, thanks to everyone for their answers, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`referee.each(function()` is being called on an array named `referee`, not a jQuery object.

Try `$.each(referee, function()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

**UPDATE**

You might also look at `.split`ing with a regex instead to see if that makes any difference:

```
var referee = referees.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: thanks, I had been switching between both of those but it still behaves the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

`referee` in your progam is the list of splitted strings, and inside your "each loop", you use the list instead of the instance. Try replacing:

```
FB.api('/'+ referee +'/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
```

with

```
FB.api('/'+ $(this) +'/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
```

Comment: thanks, when I use `$(this)` in the alert to see what it's using it says `[object Object]`